# Sending output to the stdout and a file

Tags: php

I'd like to write a script that outputs the result to the *stdout* and to the file simultaneously. Is the code below OK?

```
echo "<pre>";
ob_start();

$file = fopen("plik.txt", "w") or
    exit ("Error opening the file");

for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {   
        echo "iter#: $i\r\n";   
}

$content = ob_get_flush();
echo "</pre>";

fwrite($file, $content) or 
    exit("Error writting to the file");
```

Comment: When you say simultaneous, what exactly do you mean? What do your test(s) show, does it work as expected? If not, what doesn't seem to work?

Comment: I mean to send the output to stdout and write to file in the same time. My question is rather - is it OK to have an output before ob_start?